# O que é um “hiato” na língua portuguesa?

Tags: definição

Como sabemos o que é um *hiato* na língua portuguesa?

Existe alguma regra para realizar isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HIATO**: quando duas vogais estão juntas na mesma palavra, mas em sílabas diferentes.

Temos como exemplo:

S**A**-**Ú**-DE

PA-R**A**-**Í**-BA

S**O**-**A**R

**Nota:** em caso de as vogais fazerem parte da mesma sílaba, trata-se de um **ditongo** e não de um hiato como informado.